# Pairs in a deck of cards

Tags: probability

I had this question, and I was wondering how to do it. The question was what is the probability of not drawing a pair out of a deck of cards, and I wasn't sure how to do it could someone help me out

Comment: How many cards are you drawing?  Are you drawing with replacement or without?  In the event you are drawing more than two cards, how do you define "not drawing a pair."  Does drawing a three-of-a-kind qualify as "not drawing a pair"?

Comment: What did you try? Is the question: "what is the probability of, when drawing two cards independently, of ending up with a pair"? What is a "pair"? Two black cards of the same value, or two red cards of the same value? Or just two black card of the same value?

Comment: Assuming you are drawing only two cards without replacement and a pair is defined as normal as being two cards of the same rank regardless of suit, note that whatever the first card you draw is... regardless what it was when you go to draw the second card there are three cards of the same rank as the first remaining out of the 51 remaining cards.

Comment: @JMoravitz it's defined as drawing 2 cards without replacement, and a pair is defined as as 2 cards of equal rank, regardless of suits

Comment: @Plop it's defined as drawing 2 cards without replacing them, and they have to be the same rank, but the suit doesn't matter.

Comment: Yes, yes, we should both have noticed the first response.  Now, did you understand my explanation in my second comment?  Do you understand how I made the assertion?  Do you understand why that is enough information to complete the problem?  After having drawn your first card, whatever it was, there will remain three other cards of the same rank as the first in the deck out of 51 cards remaining to choose from for the second card...

Comment: Yes, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order mattering, all events considered:  There are $52\times 51$ possible ways to draw two cards.  The number of ways to draw two cards such that a pair is not drawn is $52\times 48$, seen by picking the first card and then picking the second card such that it is not the same rank as the first.  The probability is then $\dfrac{52\times 48}{52\times 51}$

Equivalently, one could pick the rank of the first and then the suit of the first, then the rank of the second and the suit of the second giving $\dfrac{13\times 4\times 12\times 4}{52\times 51}$

Order not mattering, all events considered:  There are $\binom{52}{2}$ possible ways to draw two cards.  The number of ways to draw two cards such that a pair is not drawn is $\binom{13}{2}\times 4\times 4$, seen by picking the two ranks simultaneously then picking the suit of the lower selected rank and then the suit of the higher selected rank.  The probability is then $\dfrac{\binom{13}{2}\times 4\times 4}{\binom{52}{2}}$

Order mattering, events simplified:  Given whatever first card was drawn, there are $48$ cards in the $51$ remaining cards which do not match the same rank as the first.  The probability is then $\dfrac{48}{51}$

All of these of course give the same answer.  Which you choose with regards to order mattering or not, when you account for suits as opposed to ranks, etc... are largely irrelevant so long as you are consistent.  Ideally, you pick whichever explanation makes the most sense to you and/or simplifies arithmetic the most.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are drawing two cards without replacement, you can determine the probability of them not being a pair through examining the second card drawn.

After drawing the first card there will now be 51 cards remaining in the deck (since you have drawn one), and there are only 3 cards remaining that can form a pair with your first card.

Now you can easily find the probability of not drawing one of those three cards, and consequently, the probability of not having a pair.